# Eventhub partition key in connection string

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

What's the correct way to write an eventhub connectionstring with the partition key (or publisher)?
I should write the partition inside the EntityPath? Could someone give me an example?
Also, is there a method to link a consumergroup to a specific partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It  should be something like below,

```
 /// <param name="connectionString">EventHub connection string with format: Endpoint=sb://namespace_DNS_Name;SharedAccessKeyName=SHARED_ACCESS_KEY_NAME;SharedAccessKey=SHARED_ACCESS_KEY;EntityPath=.</param>
```

You dont have to put the paritionKey in the connection string, it can be send with the data as follows,

```
var partitionSender = this.EventHubClient.CreatePartitionSender(partitionId);
```

Comment: yep but where and how should I put the partition key field?

Comment: understood, but there is not a way to pass this value from uri?